# Cannot run c/c++ file in Visual Studio Code in MacBOOK, even after installing Code Runner Extension in VSC

Tags: c++, c, macos, visual-studio

I want to run c/c++ code in my MacBook Pro. For this I install Visual Studio Code in my mac. Also I install gcc compiler through terminal.

I have install C/C++ extension and Code Runner in the Visual Studio Code. Then I open the folder from VS Code where I usually save all my c/c++ files. And on VS code I right click on the code and select "Run Code" option but the code doesn't run. Also there is no problem showing in the "Problems" tab ...

Can anyone here to help me in this situation to run a my c files in VS codes.

**N:B:** In my previous time I used to XCode for this task ...But I don't want the massive app for this task.